# Definite integral involving hyperbolic cosine

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration, hyperbolic-functions

I have had no experience so far with hyperbolic functions so any help will be appreciated. This is on the chapter of complex integration but I would especially appreciate it if you could turn this into a real integration problem. If not, one should just go with what he/she has.

Prove that: $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} = \frac{\pi}{\cosh\left (\frac{\pi}{2} \right)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$, we have
$$\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} = 2\dfrac{\cos(x)}{e^x + e^{-x}} = \dfrac2{e^x} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{1+e^{-2x}} = \dfrac2{e^x} \cos(x) \left(1 - e^{-2x} + e^{-4x} - e^{-6x} + \cdots\right)$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} = 2 \cos(x) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}e^{-(2k+1)x}$$
Now $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx = 4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\cos(x) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}e^{-(2k+1)x} \right)dx$$
Hence, we get that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x) e^{-(2k+1)x} \right)dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x) e^{-(k+1)x} dx = \dfrac{(2k+1)}{(2k+1)^2 + 1}$$
Hence,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx = 4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k (2k+1)}{(2k+1)^2+1} = 4 \times \dfrac{\pi}{4} \text{sech}(\pi/2) = \pi \text{sech}(\pi/2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x+e^{-x}} d x & =2 \Re \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} e^{x i}}{1+e^{-2x}} d x \\
& =2 \Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{(-1+i) x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k e^{-2 k x} d x \\
& =2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(2k+1-i) x} d x \\
& =-2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \Re\left[\frac{e^{-(2 k+1-i) k}}{-(2 k+1-i)}\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \Re\left(\frac{1}{2 k+1-i}\right) \\
&= 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 k+1)}{(2 k+1)^2+1} \\ &=2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} \operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \quad  \textrm{ (See footnote for details)} \\&= \frac{\pi}{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$ \boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{\cosh x} d x=\frac{\pi}{\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}}$$

Footnote:
$$
\begin{aligned} 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 k+1)}{(2 k+1)^2+1} = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{2 k+1-i}+\frac{1}{2 k+1+i}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{k+\frac{1-i}{2}}-\frac{1}{-k-1+\frac{1-i}{2}}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+\frac{1-i}{2}} \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2} \csc \left(\pi \cdot \frac{1-i}{2}\right) \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2} \sec \left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right) \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$